# When will Ubuntu be fully compatible with the XPS 13 2 in 1(7390)

Tags: xps, compatibility

I've recently bought the  Dell XPS 13 2 in 1(7390) but Ubuntu isn't completely compatible with it yet - no touchscreen or webcam. So I would like to know when I can expect a compatible version.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to ask Dell that.

Comment: I think it is fair to ask when the community might add support for new hardware. The trouble is, this could be fairly opinion based if the hardware in question is not yet on the roadmap. This question should probably be answered by identifying the packages that could support the hardware and pointing OP to the maintainers of those packages.